# Get all data from a table that contains two foreign key data

Tags: mysql

Table **instructor**: `ID, name, dept_name, salary`

Table **student**: `ID, name, dept_name, tot_cred`

Table **advisor**: `s_ID, i_ID` which contains student id and instructor id for the two table.

I need to find all the `instructor` and `student's` name where  the `department` of the `advisor` is `CComp.Sci`

I can find all the id of the instructor and student whrer the intructor is fom Computer science. And only the name of the students.

But can't figure out both the name at the same time.

I wrote this:

```
SELECT student.name  
  FROM student 
 WHERE student.ID in (SELECT advisor.s_ID 
                        FROM advisor
                           , instructor 
                       WHERE advisor.i_ID = instructor.ID 
                         and instructor.dept_name = 'Comp.Sci')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using "where .. in (..)" will give you bad performance, also it will not allow you to get the data from the table in the where clause.

Here is a solution if you mean to get the result of instructor name side alone with student name.

```
SELECT S.name AS Student,I.name AS Instructor 
FROM Students AS S 
JOIN Advisor AS A ON A.s_ID = S.Id
JOIN Instructor AS I ON I.Id = A.i_ID
WHERE I.dept_name = 'Comp.Sci'
```

*notice that I used alias

** if you want for example to get all students even those who lack instructor use LEFT JOIN

Comment: I found by myself also. `SELECT S.name AS Student,I.name AS Instructor FROM student AS S JOIN advisor AS A ON A.s_ID = S.Id JOIN instructor AS I ON I.Id = A.i_ID WHERE I.dept_name = 'Comp.Sci'`

Answer (score 1):

The root solution I think you need here is just a simple join between the three tables.  But since you need a single list of both student and instructor names, this complicates things.  One option is to union together a query which finds the matching students along with a query which finds the matching instructors.

```
SELECT s.name, 'student' AS type
FROM student s
INNER JOIN advisor a
    ON s.ID = a.s_ID
INNER JOIN instructor i
    ON a.i_ID = i.ID
WHERE i.dept_name = 'CComp.Sci'
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT i.name, 'instructor'
FROM student s
INNER JOIN advisor a
    ON s.ID = a.s_ID
INNER JOIN instructor i
    ON a.i_ID = i.ID
WHERE i.dept_name = 'CComp.Sci'
```